# $k$-out-of-$n$ combinations, arranged as matrices, satisfying certain conditions

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

**Notations.**

(i). $1^k:$ $k$ bits long string of $1's$.

(ii). $f^{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}(x):$ Given $x \in \{0,1\}^n$, select the $k$ bits at indices $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k$, in order, from $x$, to generate a $k$ bits long sub-string of $x$. The indices are chosen such that: $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_k \leq n$.

**Problem Statement.**
Given $x,y \in \{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}^n$, generate $\dbinom{n}{k}$ matrices, called $A^{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}_{x,y}$, such that each matrix entry is defined as:

\begin{align}\label{eqn}
a_{x,y} &=
\begin{cases}
1       & \text{if }~ \neg f^{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}(x) \vee f^{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}(y) = 1^k \\
0       &\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
\end{align}

The problem is to count the average number of $a_{x,y} = 1$ entries in the $\dbinom{n}{k}$ matrices, $A^{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}_{x,y}$, where $f^{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}(x) \neq f^{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}(y)$.

**Attempt.** I tried to solve the problem and came up with the following forumla:
\begin{equation}\label{eq} \sum\limits_{w=1}^n \dbinom{n}{w} \cdot \sum\limits_{m=1}^w \dbinom{n-m}{k} \cdot 2^{n-w} \qquad \qquad \end{equation}

To get to the above equation, we consider the strings $x \in \{0,1\}^n$ in ascending order of hamming weights, $||x||_1$. So, we begin by counting the number of $y \in \{0,1\}^n$ that disagree with the $x$ at exactly one $1$ index (i.e., some $i$ such that $x[i] = 1)$, hence from such $y$ we must choose from the remaining $n-1$ indices. There are $2^{n-w}$ options to fill the rest of the $n-w$ indices in such strings $y~(n-w-m \text{ number of } 1's \text{ and } m~0's$ are fixed), and we may choose any $k$ out of the $n-1$ indices from such $y$. To account for the the total number of binary strings of hamming weights $w = 1$ to $w=n$, we added the term $\dbinom{n}{w}$.

**Issue.** This solution first selects the $y's$ satisfying a certain condition (i.e., $x \neq y$) and then picks $k$ indices/bits from those while a proper solution should consider the $k$ combinations of indices first and then evaluate whether the desired condition is met for those indices. Hence, the solution inevitably undercounts.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you worked out any examples for small values of $n$ and $k$?

Comment: @SteveKass I've added my attempt at solving the problem but as it has some issues, I did not add it initially. Thanks!

Comment: You note “This solution counts the total number of $a_{x,y}=1$ entries in all matrices, but we want the average number for each matrix.” The average number of $1$s per matrix is the total number of $1$s in all matrices divided by the number of matrices. Also, I think you want the average (over all size-$k$ subsets of bit positions) number of pairs $(x,y)$ that can be distinguished by their bits in those positions. Shouldn’t the number of distinguishable pairs only depend on $k$, not the particular subset? [Is the domain of $x,y$ in the “Problem Statement” a typo?]

Comment: @SteveKass Yes, we can get the average but that's not the primary issue in my approach (problem statement edited). Ideally, the solution should first pick $k$-out-of-$n$ indices, $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k$, and then form the $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix $A^{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k}_{x,y}$ accordingly. You're correct, the number of distinguishable pairs depends on $k$ but as the matrix is $2^n \times 2^n$, we need to consider $k$-subsets to account for the value of $n$. Notice that the number of $x,y \in \{0,1\}^n$ such that $a_{x,y}=1$ changes for different values of $n$ (keeping $k$ unchanged).

Comment: Sorry, I still don’t get it. 1) Given $n$ and $k$, isn’t the number of $1$s in $A_{x,y}^{i_1,\dots,i_k}$ independent of the particular $k$-subset $\{i_1,\dots,i_k\}$ you choose? (If so, take the $k$ least-significant bits and it’s the answer to “For how many pairs $(x,y)\in\{0,2^n-1\}^2$ is $x\not\equiv y\!\!\!\!\mod 2^k$?” If not, can you give an explicit example of two $A$ for the same $k,n$ that have different numbers of $1$s?) 2) In “Problem Statement” you say $x,y \in \{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}^n$. I think you mean $x,y \in \{0,1\}^n$.

Comment: @SteveKass I have made some progress and I think I should be able to get to the solution soon. Once I do, I will update the question body and also add some examples.